# Como validar um formulário corretamente?

Tags: java, java-ee, jsp, servlet

Estou estudando Java EE, porém estou tendo dificuldades em realizar validações em formulários de entradas de dados. Minha servlet `CadastrarInstrutor` coleta os campos do formulário e verifica os seus conteúdos.

Abaixo encontra-se o código da minha página JSP (coloquei apenas o conteúdo do *body* da minha página, e a forma de validação ocorrendo na minha servlet.

**cadastra-instrutor.jsp**

```jsp
<%
    String erros = "";
    String converter = "";
    if (request.getAttribute("erro") != null && request.getAttribute("erroConverter") != null) {
        erros = (String) request.getAttribute("erro");
        converter = (String) request.getAttribute("erroConverter");
    }
%>

<form method="post" action="cadastroInstrutor">

    <p>Nome:
        <input type="text" name="nome"/>
        <span class="erro" style="color: red;">${erros}</span>
    </p>

    <p>Matrícula:
        <input type="text" name="matricula"/>
        <span class="erro" style="color: red;">${erros}</span>
    </p>

    <p>Conclusão de Gradução:
        <input type="text" name="graduacao"/>
        <span class="erro" style="color: red;">${erros}</span>
        <span class="erroConverter" style="color: red;">${erroConverter}</span>
    </p>

    <input type="submit" value="Enviar Dados"/>

</form>
```

**CadastrarInstrutor.java**

```java
protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
        throws ServletException, IOException {
    boolean isFormValido = true;
    try {
        String nome = request.getParameter("nome");
        String matricula = request.getParameter("matricula");
        String ano = request.getParameter("graduacao");
        if (nome.isEmpty() || matricula.isEmpty() || ano.isEmpty()) {
            request.setAttribute("erro", "Você não preencheu todos os campos!\");
            isFormValido = false;
        }
        Integer anoGraduacao = Integer.parseInt(ano);
    } catch (NullPointerException e) {
        request.setAttribute("erro", "Você não preencheu todos os campos!");
        isFormValido = false;
    } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
        request.setAttribute("erroConverter", "Apenas números são aceitos neste campo!");
        isFormValido = false;
    }

    if (isFormValido) {
        // Salvar no banco e então redirecionar para a listagem.
        response.sendRedirect("listagem-instrutor.jsp");
    } else {
        request.getRequestDispatcher("cadastro-instrutor.jsp").forward(request, response);
    }
}
```

Por definição do professor (será introduzido no futuro), por enquanto, está indisponível o uso de JSTL, por isso o uso de scriptlets. Não há o foco também em Javascript para validação do formulário.

A pergunta então é: Como vocês realizariam esta validação, e aonde a realizariam?

Comment: No servlet eu checaria se os parâmetros não são nulos antes de usar `isEmpty`. No JSP, os `{erros}` eu deixaria apenas um no inicio ou final do formulário e usaria o atributo `required` nos *inputs*. Acho que só isso pra verificar se o formulário foi preenchido, se fossem validações mais complexas eu criaria um servlet especifico para isso.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Na utilização de servlet puro eu validaria na tela mesmo, o html5 já prover esse recurso, também faria como você está fazendo mas eu criaria uma classe para cada objeto para validar os atributos dele. Digo, encapsularia as validações, entendeu?

Aqui o html5 funcionando com validações:
http://tableless.com.br/validacao-de-formularios-com-html5/

Comment: Acabei seguindo este padrão. Criei uma classe de validação, aonde ela realiza a validação de cada um dos dados, e ocorrendo os erros, eu adiciono uma mensagem à uma lista de mensagens. Caso necessário, eu poderia postar minha solução nesta pergunta para ajudar quem venha a ter tais problemas futuros com isso.